# Is there a way to monitoring Apache-Ignite split-brain using Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, ignite

I am facing an ignite split-brain from time to time and want to monitor this event when it occurs to be able to solve it in time.

Since the other information I got is from the metrics exported from Apache-Ignite itself to Prometheus, is there any way I can use the same method to get the information about split-brain?

I tried to dig into some metrics called "CurrentTopologyVersion" and "TopologyVersion" but got nothing to tell whatever it is split-brain of not.

Answer (score 0):

If different nodes have differing `CurrentTopologyVersion` then they may be in split brain. If they also have different number of active server nodes, this is also a clue.

Please note that I didn't practically see any Ignite split brains, node segmentation tends to occur some orders of magnitude more often.